# c++ asio how to mantain async object lifetime

Tags: c++, boost-asio

In asio, whenever I want to use an async object that does some asynchronous operation I have to use shared pointers because the async operation handler lives inside the io_context and if the async object is destroyed, the handler can still be called.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace std;

asio::io_context ctx;

struct Session {
    ~Session() {
        *stopped = true;
        cout << "~Session()" << endl;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<bool> stopped = std::make_shared<bool>(false);
    asio::steady_timer t{ctx};
    void async_operation() {
        t.expires_after(1s);
        t.async_wait([this, stopped = stopped](const asio::error_code &error) {
            cout << error.value() << ' ' << error.message() << endl;
            cout << "*stopped: " << *stopped << endl;
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << boolalpha;
    
    {
        Session s;
        s.async_operation();
        ctx.run_for(100ms);
        cout << "use_count: " << s.stopped.use_count() << endl;
    }
    
    ctx.run_for(2s);
}
```

output:

```
use_count: 2
~Session()
125 Operation aborted.
*stopped: true
```

But what if I want the async_operation to be a coroutine? Do I have to pass the shared pointer as an argument?
can't the interface of the Session be something like this?

```cpp
struct Session {
    auto connect(std::string_view host, std::string_view port) -> asio::awaitable<void>;
};
```

I could use lambda coroutine or I could forward the implementation of the async_operation coroutine like so:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace std;
inline constexpr auto use_tuple_awaitable = asio::as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable);

asio::io_context ctx;

struct Session {
    ~Session() {
        *stopped = true;
        cout << "~Session" << endl;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<bool> stopped = std::make_shared<bool>(false);
    asio::steady_timer t{ctx};
    auto async_operation_impl(std::shared_ptr<bool> stopped_) -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        t.expires_after(1s);
        auto &&[error] = co_await t.async_wait(use_tuple_awaitable);
        cout << error.value() << ' ' << error.message() << endl;
        cout << "*stopped: " << *stopped_ << endl;
    }
    auto async_operation() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        return async_operation_impl(stopped);
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << boolalpha;
    
    {
        Session s;
        asio::co_spawn(asio::system_executor(), s.async_operation(), asio::detached);
        cout << "use_count: " << s.stopped.use_count() << endl;
    }
    
    ctx.run_for(2s);
}
```

output:

```
use_count: 2
~Session()
125 Operation aborted.
*stopped: true
```

But this all seems like a hack rather than an elegant solution.

What is the proper way of creating asynchronous objects that can live on the stack and can be destroyed independently of `io_context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In asio, whenever I want to use an async object that does some asynchronous operation I have to use shared pointers because the async operation handler lives inside the io_context and if the async object is destroyed, the handler can still be called.

Depending on your definition of "an async object" (that's not a well-defined term). Keep in mind you can have move-only operations, which is why often `unique_ptr` is used. In fact, some operations don't require stability of reference at all and you can just move the entire handler object.

All that said, shared ownership is often easiest, and pretty common.

---

> But what if I want the async_operation to be a coroutine? Do I have to pass the shared pointer as an argument?

There's actually very little difference. `async_operation` didn't take the session object either. Instead you just captured a shared pointer into your completion handler.

What you usually do is make the entire state for the operation(s) shared:

```
struct Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    ~Session() {
        stopped = true;
        std::cout << "~Session()" << std::endl;
    }

    Session(asio::any_io_executor ex) : t{ex} {}

    asio::steady_timer t;
    std::atomic_bool   stopped = false;

    void async_operation() {
        t.expires_after(1s);
        t.async_wait([this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code error) {
            std::cout << error.value() << ' ' << error.message() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "stopped: " << stopped << std::endl;
        });
    }
};
```

Note how you capture `self = shared_from_this()` to share ownership to the `Session`, with all relevant members.

> can't the interface of the Session be something like this?

Sure. It'd be the same, but slightly simpler. The coro frame includes the stack, so you can "just" capture inside the coro:

```
struct CoSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CoSession> {
    ~CoSession() {
        stopped = true;
        std::cout << "~CoSession()" << std::endl;
    }

    std::atomic_bool stopped = false;

    asio::awaitable<void> async_operation() {
        auto self = shared_from_this();

        asio::steady_timer t{co_await asio::this_coro::executor, 1s};
        auto [error] = co_await t.async_wait(as_tuple(asio::deferred));
        std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "stopped: " << stopped << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Which you can then use like:

```
asio::io_context ctx;
auto s = std::make_shared<CoSession>();
asio::co_spawn(ctx, s->async_operation(), asio::detached);
```

If you want to avoid the "tricky" self-capture, you can also bind the session object into the coro:

```
asio::co_spawn(ctx, std::bind(&CoSession::async_operation, s), asio::detached);
// or even
asio::co_spawn(ctx, std::bind(&CoSession::async_operation, std::move(s)), asio::detached);
```

### Simplify?

If you realize that the coro stack is part of the coro state and normal C++ object lifetimes apply... you can see the more natural pattern, avoiding shared lifetime:

```
asio::awaitable<void> run_session() {
    SimpleSession local;
    co_await local.async_operation();
}
```

> Note: if you change `co_await` to `return` there, it has a life-time problem again because ***in that case*** `async_operation` doesn't complete before `local` is destructed.

### Demo Time

Demoing all approaches side-by-side:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/qdvMqah8M)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code; // non-standalone asio doens't declare error_code
namespace asio = boost::asio;

struct Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    ~Session() {
        stopped = true;
        std::cout << "~Session()" << std::endl;
    }

    Session(asio::any_io_executor ex) : t{ex} {}

    asio::steady_timer t;
    std::atomic_bool   stopped = false;

    void async_operation(unsigned line) {
        t.expires_after(1s);
        t.async_wait([this, self = shared_from_this(), line](error_code error) {
            std::cout << line << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
            std::cout << line << ": stopped = " << stopped << std::endl;
        });
    }
};

struct CoSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CoSession> {
    ~CoSession() {
        stopped = true;
        std::cout << "~CoSession()" << std::endl;
    }

    std::atomic_bool stopped = false;

    asio::awaitable<void> async_operation(unsigned line) {
        auto self = shared_from_this();

        asio::steady_timer t{co_await asio::this_coro::executor, 1s};
        auto [error] = co_await t.async_wait(as_tuple(asio::deferred));
        std::cout << line << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
        std::cout << line << ": stopped = " << stopped << std::endl;
    }
};

struct SimpleSession {
    ~SimpleSession() {
        stopped = true;
        std::cout << "~SimpleSession()" << std::endl;
    }

    std::atomic_bool stopped = false;

    asio::awaitable<void> async_operation(unsigned line) {
        asio::steady_timer t{co_await asio::this_coro::executor, 1s};
        auto [error] = co_await t.async_wait(as_tuple(asio::deferred));
        std::cout << line << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
        std::cout << line << ": stopped = " << stopped << std::endl;
    }
};

asio::awaitable<void> run_session(unsigned line) {
    SimpleSession local;
    co_await local.async_operation(line);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    
    auto delay1 = 100ms;
    auto delay2 = 2s;

    {
        std::cout << " --- Session\n";
        asio::io_context ctx;
        auto s = std::make_shared<Session>(ctx.get_executor());
        s->async_operation(__LINE__);
        ctx.run_for(delay1);
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": use_count: " << s.use_count() << std::endl;

        s.reset();
        ctx.run_for(delay2);
    }

    {
        std::cout << " --- CoSession, unbound\n";
        asio::io_context ctx;
        auto s = std::make_shared<CoSession>();
        asio::co_spawn(ctx, s->async_operation(__LINE__), asio::detached);
        ctx.run_for(delay1);
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": use_count: " << s.use_count() << std::endl;
        s.reset();
        ctx.run_for(delay2);
    }

    {
        std::cout << " --- CoSession, bound\n";
        asio::io_context ctx;
        auto s = std::make_shared<CoSession>();
        asio::co_spawn(ctx, std::bind(&CoSession::async_operation, s, __LINE__), asio::detached);
        ctx.run_for(delay1);
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": use_count: " << s.use_count() << std::endl;
        s.reset();
        ctx.run_for(delay2);
    }

    {
        std::cout << " --- CoSession, move-bound\n";
        asio::io_context ctx;
        auto s = std::make_shared<CoSession>();
        asio::co_spawn(ctx, std::bind(&CoSession::async_operation, std::move(s), __LINE__), asio::detached);
        ctx.run_for(delay1);
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": use_count: " << s.use_count() << std::endl;
        s.reset();
        ctx.run_for(delay2);
    }

    {
        std::cout << " --- SimpleSession, Coro lifetime\n";
        asio::io_context ctx;
        asio::co_spawn(ctx, run_session(__LINE__), asio::detached);
        ctx.run_for(delay2);
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
 --- Session
78: use_count: 2
76: Success
76: stopped = false
~Session()
 --- CoSession, unbound
90: use_count: 2
88: Success
88: stopped = false
~CoSession()
 --- CoSession, bound
101: use_count: 3
99: Success
99: stopped = false
~CoSession()
 --- CoSession, move-bound
112: use_count: 0
110: Success
110: stopped = false
~CoSession()
 --- SimpleSession, Coro lifetime
120: Success
120: stopped = false
~SimpleSession()
```

Comment: is it safe to copy shared pointer inside the coroutine? `auto self = shared_from_this();` what if by the time the coroutine runs for the first time, `*this` is already destructed?

Comment: That's part of why I showed the `bind` solutions. You're right to question whether it would be correct without the 100ms delay - I'm not immediately sure. It will depend on whether the coroutine is eagerly or lazily executed. For one thing I know that Boost Async (proposed) has the possibility to choose this behaviour. I would **expect** Asio's  awaitable promise types to be completely lazy, but I haven't checked.